# Spivak's Calculus, Appendix to Chapter 8, "Uniform Continuity", Problem 3 Solution Interpretation

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Spivak's Calculus, appendix to chapter 8, "Uniform Continuity", problem 3:

> Use a "bisection argument" (page 142) to give another proof of Theorem
> 1.

The theorem mentioned in the question:

> Theorem 1: if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is uniformly
> continuous on $[a,b]$.

The solution in the solution manual

> Given $\epsilon>0$, suppose $f$ is not $\epsilon$-good on $[a,b]$.
> Then, by the Lemma, either $f$ is not $\epsilon$-good on $[a,
> > \frac{a+b}{2}]$ or $f$ is not $\epsilon$-good on $[\frac{a+b}{2},b]$.
> Let $I_1$ be one of the halves on which $f$ is not $\epsilon$-good.
> Now bisect $I_1$, and let $I_2$ be a half on which $f$ is not
> $\epsilon$-good. Etc. Let $x_0$ be a point in all $I_n$. Choose
> $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then
> $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon/2$. It follows that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ and
> $|y-x_0|<\delta$, then $f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, ie, $f$ is
> $\epsilon$-good on $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$. But some $I_n$ is
> contained in this interval, a contradiction.

Note that $f$ being $\epsilon$-good on an interval means that for a given $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x\forall y$ $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

The Lemma cited in the proof is

> Let $a<b<c$ and let $f$ be continuous on the interval $[a,c]$. Let
> $\epsilon>0$, and suppose that statements $(i)$ and $(ii)$ hold:
>
> i) $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,b]$
>
> ii) $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on
> $[b,c]$
>
> Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,c]$

Here is how I would "narrate" this proof:

Given $\epsilon>0$ we assume that $f$ is not $\epsilon$-good on $[a,b]$.

If we consider the lemma above with $c$ being $b$ and $b$ being $\frac{a+b}{2}$, then this assumption is the negation of the consequent in the lemma. This means that we can assert the negation of the antecedent.

The solution then claims that this means that either i) or ii) is false, ie, either $f$ isn't $\epsilon$-good on $[a,\frac{a+b}{2}]$ or it isn't $\epsilon$-good on $[\frac{a+b}{2},b]$. **What if $f$ isn't $\epsilon$-good on both of the intervals?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters is that $f$ isn't $\varepsilon$-good on **one** of those two intervals. It's not an exclusive or. In other words, what it is being done here is to prove that if $f$ is not $\varepsilon$-good on $[a,b]$, then it's not $\varepsilon$-good on $\left[a,\frac{a+b}2\right]$ **or** it is not $\varepsilon$-good on $\left[\frac{a+b}2,b\right]$. But it may well not be $\varepsilon$-good on both of them.

Comment: Made minor corrections to the language.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you.